# How to require plug-in module in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, mocha.js

I'm testing a server (not done by me) using Mocha framework and [SuperAgent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/) module, however I need to test the server Ouath protocol.
I find the [superagent-oauth](https://github.com/LearnBoost/superagent-oauth) module in order to make sign request.

However, when I require the module I get the following error

> TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object

My code, follows the readme in the superagent-oauth repo, and it is

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
var log = require('./log.js');
var Oauth = require('node-oauth');
var oauth = new Oauth({..});

require('superagent-oauth')(superagent);
```

Then when running the test I got the TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object.

When using superagent I just do

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
agent = superagent.agent();
```

But I don't know how to use/require the superagent-oauth module. So what's the way to do it correctly?
Thank you

Added the trace

> 2) Login 'Username:Password' test: POST with a valid login logins into
>   the AM with a valid login:
>        TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
>         at Function.keys (native)
>         at Request.query (/home/maldo/testingAM/node_modules/superagent-oauth/superagent-oauth.js:22:23)
>         at Context. (/home/maldo/testingAM/loginUserPass.js:74:6)
>         at Test.Runnable.run (/home/maldo/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:196:15)
>         at Runner.runTest (/home/maldo/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:343:10)
>         at Runner.runTests.next (/home/maldo/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:389:12)
>         at next (/home/maldo/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:269:14)
>         at Runner.hooks (/home/maldo/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:278:7)
>         at next (/home/maldo/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:226:23)
>         at Runner.hook (/home/maldo/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:246:5)
>         at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)

I got this trace in the file loginUserPass a couple of times always in the .query() statament of the agent. This happens when in the OauthAM.js I added superagent-ouath require.

Comment: you should post the whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Have you done `npm install` to retrieve all the module dependencies from npm? It seems like the dependencies for [superagent](https://npmjs.org/package/superagent) are not available perhaps?

New dependencies are installed with (and put into `package.json` file) with `npm install superagent --save`.

That way you'll get all the dependencies that the superagent module needs.

Comment: Yes my package.json have all the dependencies and they are installed, even they have been deleted and re-installed

Comment: @Maldo: It seems like the dependency is there. How does the test look like that fails? In your stack trace it says loginUserPass.js line 74 col 6.

Comment: >`it('logins in to the AM with a valid login', function (done) {
>   agent2
>    .post(route.server)
>    .query(route.loginPost)
>    .send('userId=example1')
>    .send('userPass=1234')
>    .end(function (req, res) {
>//https://localhost:8443/AM/?0-1.IFormSubmitListener-form
>//console.log(util.inspect(res));
>     >res.should.have.property('statusCode').that.equals(200);
>res['redirects'][0].should.have.string(route.server+route.userPage);
>res['text'].should.contain('example1@hotmail.com');
>res['text'].should.contain('Log out');
>     done();
>    });
>  });`

Line 74 is the .query()

Comment: @Maldo: could you please edit your question to include that and point out where line 74 col 6 is?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same error message while installing vows on a new project created with `npm init`.  This GitHub issues discussion suggested adding the following line to the `package.json` file for the project (i.e. the project you're trying to create, not the one you're trying to install):

```
 "dependencies": {}
```

This resolved it for me.  Of course, you mentioned you have dependencies installed in your package.json, so this answer is more for others who might search for the error message.

https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install/issues/9